# Multiple ways to identify user / mysql, pdo, php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a database table `users`. Every user has at least userid. Two other optional values are `email` and `username` (must contain letters also so it's never mixed to userid! - I know). They're all unique.

I have one method for getting details (row) from users table. Param `$userIdentifier` can be userid, email or username.

What I want, is that the query would work for all 3 types (mostly it's userid).

```
$user->getData(111203432);
$user->getData("myemail@admin.com");
$user->getData("Admin");

if email: *WHERE email=...*
if userid: *WHERE userid=...*
if username: *WHERE username=...*
```

Right now my query is not working (and checking for usernames is missing). I have tried various things, this is the latest:

```
if(is_numeric($userIdentifier)) {
    // also tried if_int
    $sql_getUserByValue = "users.userid";
    $bindType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
} elseif(filter_var($userIdentifier, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $sql_getUserByValue = "users.email";
    $bindType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
} else {
    return false; // user not found
}

global $main_dbconnection;

$query = $main_dbconnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users 
    ..... some inner joins here because different user types in diff. tables ...
    WHERE $sql_getUserByValue=:userIdentifier");

$query->bindParam(':userIdentifier', $userIdentifier, $bindType);
$query->execute();
// Fetch result if found >>>
```

Not also giving any errors. Just 0 rows found (method returns false).

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the users table is HUGE, or really slow, you might be better to skip autodetection and **use one single query** for all:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE users.userid = x
UNION
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE users.email= x
UNION
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE users.username = x
```

Or in one query, but might be slower (depends on your indexes)

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE users.userid = x
OR
users.email= x
OR
users.username = x
```

Comment: Wow. This is so simple. How did I never though it could be done so easly... I feel so stupid right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use OR in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM users ... WHERE email=... OR userid=... OR username=...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users
...
WHERE (email = ? OR userid = ? OR username = ?)
```